# Django how to order by many to many occurences

Tags: python, django

let's say I have 2 models:

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    recipe = models.TextField()
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient)

class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
```

and I want to know what ingredient is the most used in all the recipes.

How do I query that?

Comment: This is a simplified example but my real code uses a generic relation and Django chokes on that (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations-and-aggregation) A possible solution to that is to use Django Generic Aggregation: https://github.com/coleifer/django-generic-aggregation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read about aggregation and annotations at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/

To get the name of the most common ingredient:

```
from django.db.models import Count
most_common = Ingredient.objects.annotate(num_recipes=Count('recipe')).order_by('-num_recipes')[0]
print most_common.name
```

Comment: Thanks for the link, that's what I'm reading right now but your example sheds much light on this!